# UnicodeDammit: detwingle crashes on a website

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup

I’m scraping websites and use [BeautifulSoup4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse them. As the websits can have *really* random char sets, I use [UnicodeDammit.detwingle](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#inconsistent-encodings) to ensure that I feed proper data to BeautifulSoup. It worked fine... until it crashed. One website causes the code to break. The code to build "soup" looks like this:

```
u = bs.UnicodeDammit.detwingle( html_blob ) <--- here it crashes
u = bs.UnicodeDammit( u.decode('utf-8'), 
                      smart_quotes_to='html', 
                      is_html = True )
u = u.unicode_markup
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup( u )
```

And the error (standard Python-Unicode hell duo)

```
  File ".../something.py", line 92, in load_bs_from_html_blob
    u = bs.UnicodeDammit.detwingle( html_blob )
  File ".../beautifulsoup4-4.1.3-py2.7.egg/bs4/dammit.py", line 802, in detwingle
    return b''.join(byte_chunks)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0:
ordinal not in range(128)
```

The offending website is [this one](http://www.diapers.com/p/similac-advance-ready-to-feed-32-oz-6-pk-7580)

**Question:** How to make a *proper and bulletproof* website source decoding?

Comment: For debugging, I'd recommend opening the dump file with ``'wb'`` instead of ``'w'`` and just using ``fh.write(html_blob)``. Hope this helps. (that'll open the file as binary and not as text, so python won't try to re-encode the output you're writing if it's binary)

Comment: @JonasWielicki: thanks, I totally missed that point. I edited the question and removed this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This website is not a special case in terms of character encoding at all, it's perfectly valid utf-8 with even the http header set correctly. It then follows that your code would have crashed on any website encoded in utf-8 with code points beyond ASCII.

<del>It is also evident from the documentation, that `UnicodeDammit.detwingle` takes an unicode string. You are passing it `html_blob`, and the variable naming suggests that it's not a decoded unicode string.</del> (Misunderstanding)

To handle any website encoding is not trivial in the case the http header or markup lies about the encoding or is not included at all. You need to perform various heuristics and even then you won't get it right. But this website is sending the charset header correctly and has been encoded correctly in that charset.

---

Interesting trivia. The only beyond ASCII text in the website are these javascript comments (after being decoded as utf-8):

```
image = new Array(4); //¶¨ÒåimageÎªÍ¼Æ¬ÊýÁ¿µÄÊý×é 
image[0] = 'sample_BG_image01.png' //±³¾°Í¼ÏóµÄÂ·¾¶
```

If you then encode those to ISO-8859-1, and decode the result as GB2312, you get:

```
image = new Array(4); //定义image为图片数量的数组
image[0] = 'sample_BG_image01.png' //背景图象的路径
```

Which google chinese -> english, translates to:

```
image = new Array(4); //Defined image of the array of the number of images
image[0] = 'sample_BG_image01.png' //The path of the background image
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you have then a working recipe how to decode pages properly, without crashing? `dewingle` + `utf8` worked for me in most of the cases, now I see it is not that bulletproof as I thought...

Comment: Hm, I at least do not run into decoding errors when following the HTML spec, that is, reading the Content-Type header and if that is not present, look for a matching <meta> tag. If that doesn't help I try utf8 and then latin1 (compare [this function](https://github.com/horazont/xmpp-crowd/blob/master/foomodules/URLLookup.py#L46) and [that function](https://github.com/horazont/xmpp-crowd/blob/master/foomodules/URLLookup.py#L227), which do exactly that)